# PHP not stopping the include (break)

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my script to find all of the PHP files in my include directory and put them in to an array (I've done the array part). Then, the script does a for loop to check if the GET request matches the current position value in the array (or whatever you want to call it).

But, if it doesn't find it at all.. it will include the default page, but obviously if it does it'll include the file it matched.

The problem is.. the break command isn't working at all. So, it's including the default page if it's been matched. Please help.

```
   <?php

 if(!defined("PLUGIN")){
    echo "You cannot view this file directly.";
 } else {
    $glob = glob("inc/*.php");
    $count = count($glob);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $explode = explode("/", $glob[$i]);
        $explode2 = explode(".", $explode[1]);
        if($_GET["page"] == $explode2[0]){
            include $glob[$i];
            break;
        } include_once "default.php";
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: the condition isn't met.

Comment: Your code could be much simpler with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) and using [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename)

Comment: Also, include_once "default.php" should be put outside the loop and run if a flag is set inside the loop. Otherwise you could run include_once length-1 times, in worst case.

Answer (score 4):

As it stands now, your loop will include the default page on EVERY iteration of the loop, until it matches that get/explode combination.

As well, using explode for analyzing file paths is poor practice. Instead, use `path_info()`:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($glob as $file) {
    $basename = path_info($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    if ($basename == $_GET['page']) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    } else {
        include($basename); // probably need to adjust this to make it a full filename
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    include('default.php'); // include this only if no other match was found.
}
```

Comment: 1+ for also putting the "default.php" include outside the loop. Which otherwise is the source of the problem of being included when not wanted.